# How can i get he value of selected checbkoxlist item at code behind file s that is filled by a string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i take the value of selected checbkoxlist items that is filled by a string array? I use that code but it is only working if i filled checkboxlist from manually but if i filled it from database and then convert it into array and set to checkbox list it is not working.

```
Aspx form:


    <div>
         <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkUsers" runat="server"  >



            </asp:CheckBoxList>


        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click1" 
            Text="Button" />
        </div>


Cd file:


string s=string.Empty;
            List<String> YrStrList = new List<string>();
            // Loop through each item.
            foreach (ListItem item in this.chkUsers.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {


                    // If the item is selected, add the value to the list.
                    YrStrList.Add(item.Value);
                }


            }
           // s = j.ToString();
            String YrStr = String.Join(";", YrStrList.ToArray());
            Response.Write(String.Concat("Selected Items: ", YrStr));
```

Comment: Hey Mate, Are you binding to you checkbox list on page load?

Comment: Also please format your code properly. it is very hard to read the way it is now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's a bit hard to work out your exact scenario please have at look at the following example to see if it helps.

Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkUsers" runat="server"  ></asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:Button ID="SumitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="SumitButton_Click" />
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            BindData();
        }
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
           string[] myArray = {"a","b","c"};

            foreach (string item in myArray)
            {
                chkUsers.Items.Add(item);
            }
            chkUsers.Items[1].Selected = true;
    }

    protected void SumitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = chkUsers.SelectedItem;
        Response.Write(x);
    }
```

I think you simply need to ask the checkboxlist what the selected item is?

```
 var x = chkUsers.SelectedItem;
```

However, if this doesn't help please update your scenario and I'll take another look.

Lastly welcome.

Alternate BindData and submitclick options (these may better suit your needs)

```
    private void BindData()
    {
           string[] myArray = {"a","b","c"};

            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("key");
            dt.Columns.Add("value");

            dt.Rows.Add(1,"a");
            dt.Rows.Add(2,"b");
            dt.Rows.Add(3,"c");

            chkUsers.DataTextField = "value";
            chkUsers.DataValueField = "value";
            chkUsers.DataSource = dt;
            chkUsers.DataBind();
    }

    protected void SumitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in chkUsers.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
                Response.Write(item.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks...it worked for me... actually on page load i didn't place  if (!IsPostBack)  condition so problems is occured in my code